# div style absolute in a table cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a div with position absolute and `width:100%` inside a table cell and the width is calculated to window width not to table cell width. The table cell width is also variable so I need that the width of absolute div to be the same as table cell width. How can I do that?

Comment: can you show us your html & css until now?

Answer (score 1):

From w3schools.com

An absolute position element is positioned **relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static**.

That part often gets overlooked I think.

So, try setting the td to position:relative and see if that gets you what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I got this to work:

```
<table border="1" class='rel'>
    <tr>
        <td><div class='abs'>row 1, cell 1</div></td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.rel { 
    position: relative; 
}

.abs { 
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 1px;  /* offset because of table border */
    left: 1px;
}
```

Notice the relative style is applied to the table not the tr or td. When I applied it to the td (what i expected was going to be necessary) it did not work in Chrome. Here is a jsFiddle for you to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/bNweT/1/

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: This fails on FireFox...still looking a bit.

Comment: After playing around a bit, I could not get it to work on FireFox unless I added another div inside the table cell to act as the relative parent container. Here is an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bNweT/2/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this can be done only via JavaScript.

#### Update

I tried width: auto;, but if it has position absolute it does not take the width of the parent element in DOM.

(I am testing in Chrome and Firefox)