# DIV with "position:absolute;bottom:0" doesn't stick to the bottom of the container in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, positioning

I have this HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stylish Web Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            div.table { display: table;}
            div.tableRow { display: table-row;}
            div.tableCell { display: table-cell;}
            div.contentWrapper { width: 100%; height: 760px; position: relative;
                margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
            div.footerBar { width: inherit; height: 60px; background-image: url("BarBG.png");
                background-repeat: repeat-x; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table contentWrapper">
            <div class="tableRow">&#160;</div>
            <div class="footerBar">&#160;</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The footer is supposed to appear at the bottom of the page, and it does so in Opera and Chrome; However, in Firefox, there's a lot of empty room following the footer. What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Here's a screenshot: [The blue highlight is the footer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgLXW.jpg)

(Please note: "position: fixed" is not what I want; I want the footer to show up at the bottom of the page, not the browser window.)

Comment: Have you try with another doctype because DOCTYPE HTML is NOT a standard yet ? [http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)

Comment: may be you want an sticky footer http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Jean-Charles: I doubt it would make much difference in a recent browser; they aren't going to treat a DOCTYPE wrongly just because the standard isn't complete.

Comment: @jame-Charles; html5 doctype means it's not accept by the w3c but browsers implement it.

Comment: @Matthew and Sandepp: Ok html 5 doctype is support by recents browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5), but we don't know the version of the FF used. I just try to eliminate bad solutions... I've never said this is the solution. Ajith, Wich version do you use ?

Comment: Interesting. If I comment out the `display: table;` then the background position appears where I'd expect it to. I don't know much about `display: table` and how it should affect things, though. Digging in, it looks like you might be running into [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256004/firefox-issue-with-displayabsolute-in-a-table-cell).

Comment: I'm also suspecting a relation to [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168#c11), though technially that doesn't seem to relate to `table` elements, only cells. But your problem certainly seems to be showing an incompatibility between `display: table` and `position: relative` in Firefox. Slightly icky though it is, [turning your single table/wrapper into a separate table and wrapper div, and positioning the div while leaving the table as-is seems to produce a decent result](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/bcGLp/3/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue in Firefox is caused by `display:table`. Essentially you are telling Firefox to treat this element as a table.

In Firefox `position:relative` is not supported on table elements. It isn't a bug though, as in the spec the treatment of `position:relative` table elements is undefined.

This means that in your example the footer is being positioned relative to the window and not the container.

One solution is to use `display:block` instead or just remove the `display` rule entirely. You will see the footer will drop down to its rightful place.

A second solution would be to wrap another non-table div around the container and set `position:relative` to that instead.

A third option is to add `position:relative` to the body. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/NbVTH/

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative; /* add this */
}
```

Comment: So that was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What version of FF do you have? In FF 6 it displays correctly: http://screencast.com/t/zAjuG8FP99nX

Have you cleared the cache? Maybe there's something left from previous versions of the page.

Did you close the Firebug window? That pushes the content up when open.

Later edit: the last line means: "after you close firebug, scrollbars disappear and div is at the bottom"

Comment: Seems to work for me in Firefox 3.5.5, too, unless I'm misunderstanding what's needed. ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/bcGLp/1/)).

Comment: Actually, I take that back. [Now I've put a background colour on the content wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/bcGLp/2/), I think I can see the empty space @Ajith is talking about. Works fine in other browsers (even including IE!), though.

Comment: The screenshot you've linked to quite clearly shows vertical scrollbars. If you scroll down to the bottom, you will see just as in the OP's screenshot the footer is no longer at the bottom.

Comment: @tw16 - scrollbars appear only as long as firebug is open. when i close it, no scrollbars and div goes to bottom

Comment: @marius: I think you are missing the point of the question. The reason there are no scrollbars when Firebug is closed, is because you must have a window that is taller than 760px. However, some people might have smaller screens or might be browsing in a smaller window. The **main issue** is that when you have to scroll down the footer is not stuck to the bottom of the container e.g. For you when Firebug is open if you scroll to the bottom you will see that the footer stays in the middle of the page.