# "position:absolute;" with "bottom:0;" instead "position:absolute;" doesn't stick to bottom of container in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-position

The following iScroll demo works in Safari and Chrome, but not in Firefox (I'm using 9.0.1)

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/ipad/

I've tried everything I can think of to try and solve this problem and I've looked at other questions on this same issue, such as this question. Nothing has worked so far.
[DIV with "position:absolute;bottom:0" doesn't stick to the bottom of the container in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321798/div-with-positionabsolutebottom0-doesnt-stick-to-the-bottom-of-the-contain)

Here are a few observations I've made:

- Adding something like `bottom:-300px` to `nav` and `article` makes the background show. I can't fire out why.
- Adding `height:100%` to `nav` and `article` makes the background show at the same height as the sibling header.
- The problem is independent of iScroll. You can comment out iScroll instantiation from the javascript and the html/css alone don't work in Firefox, but work in Safari and Chrome.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's a jsFiddle to save people the time:
http://jsfiddle.net/aQf7Y/

Comment: Mootools isn't being used. It's just the default framework on jsFiddle and I didn't bother to change it. It isn't being used in the above fiddle.

Comment: Appears to be a problem with the `display:-moz-box`

Comment: I'd use as few non-standard things as I can get away with, myself.  It simplifies life a lot...

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use absolute positioning inside a XUL box.  Absolute positioning is not supported in XUL, so the position style is simply ignored.

I suggest not using `display: -moz-box`, or for that matter `display: -webkit-box` or `display: box`, and certainly not if you expect them to behave the same.  The first of these is a XUL box, the second of these is a very early CSS3 flexbox draft (which is totally different from a XUL box), and the third of these doesn't exist and never will: CSS3 flexbox is using `display: flexbox`, which behaves quite differently from both `-moz-box` and `-webkit-box`.

Comment: Awesome. Didn't know two much about these new specifications. Is it best to forego all these CSS3 features entirely or are there one or two rules there you'd keep?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug to me. For some reason the `nav` and `article`, though set to `bottom: 0;` are computing to `bottom: 298px;` which is actually setting it to the bottom of the `header` element, rather than aligning with the bottom of the `relative` positioned container.

I have no idea why. Again, as best I can tell it is a bug.

Comment: Go ahead and comment out the Javascript and you'll see that it still doesn't behave the same in Firefox as in Chrome and Safari. It's not a javascript issue at all, I just left the Javascript in their to preserve the fidelity of the original use case, in case someone can offer an alternative solution for what is trying to be accomplished. I hope it isn't a bug, but I believe you may be right.

Comment: Actually, I don't know why I mentioned the script. I had already noted that it was not javascript by turning it off. I think I was tired (it was past midnight my time when I answered). I am going to remove the javascript comment in my answer.