# How to position absolute positioned element relative to parent table cell

Tags: html, css

I got row with cells that have `position:relative'`, inside them I got `select` elements with `position:absolute`. The problem is when I add for example `top:0` the select is going to top of page and not to top of table cell -Why??

```
<div class='content'>
...
<tr class="search">
<td>...</td><td>...</td><td>
<select name="source" id="id_source" class="ui-corner-all" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Test1</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="owner" id="id_owner" class="ui-corner-all" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">admin</option>
<option value="2">Janusz</option>
</select></td></tr>
...
</div>
```

and css

```
.search td {
position:relative;
vertical-align: top;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}
.content select[multiple=multiple]{
height:1.5em;
background-color:#D4CCB0;
position: absolute;
padding:4px;
top:0px
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Chrome but not in FF. This appears to be a known 13+ year old bug with FF (see http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256004/firefox-issue-with-displayabsolute-in-a-table-cell). Example of it working in Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zZCYx/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Firefox support position: relative on table elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148041/does-firefox-support-position-relative-on-table-elements)

Comment: currently I use workaround enclosing selects in `<div style="position:relative">`

Answer (score 0):

when I comment out `top:0;`, the select boxes go into their place

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/zZCYx/1/)

Comment: but this is not the point here they should go to top of first not static parent

Comment: @Lord_JABA , Gotcha. What exactly are you wanting it to do? Without the `top:0;`, it looks and works the same in FF and Chrome. I'm sure there's an easy fix.

Comment: I want to position element relatively to parent td element